# Find Kth match result in an array?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

A while back i was able to find a method to locate errors in my documents.

I haven't been able to re-purpose it to search for keywords instead of errors - could use some help with that.

Heres what I have..

Returning the first error address found:

```
=ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:200)/ISERROR(B1:B200), 1), COLUMN(B1:B1), 1, 1)
```

Returning the third error address found:
(you can modify that to whichever match you want by changing the number 3)

```
=ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(1:200)/ISERROR(B1:B200), 3), COLUMN(B1:B1), 1, 1)
```

And returning the last error address found:

```
=ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW(1:200)/ISERROR(B1:B200), 1), COLUMN(B1:B1), 1, 1)
```

Essentially I want to do the same thing but look for "DOG" or whatever instead of errors. I was able to read on what aggregate does but how that ties in with the division done there is beyond me and probably only in the realm of you pros out there :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

`ISERROR(B1:B200)`

to

`(B1:B200="DOG")`

Comment: Nope i just get a #NUM! error.

Comment: I've missed the brackets, it works for me

Comment: I'll probably die of old age before i understand how that made a difference. Do you have any idea how to extend that search to 3 columns while we are at it?